# Is there a way to find out the date and time when certain files have been deleted on WIndows 2008 R2 server

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there a way to find out the date and time when certain known files have been deleted (by RDP access) on a Windows 2008 R2 Webserver? They have not been moved to the bin.

As far as I know there are no logs (or are there?). The only thing I can think of is an undelete tool that checkes the system. There isn't really a need to recover the files, we just need to know when it happened (and subsequently who did it). If this is a recommended way - can you recommend a possibly free, safe undelete tool?

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable Auditing

It's to late for past files but this will track for future file deletions.

There are third party tools to recover files but to see who deleted it, not that I am aware of.